# Delete a line in file if it is empty in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How to delete a empty line in file?

When i searched for it , people are creating another file to move non empty lines like follows

```
gc c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} > c:\FileWithNoEmptyLines.txt
```

Is there any way to delete the line in the source file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip lines that match a space, a tab or a line break:

```
(Get-Content c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt) | `
  Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | `
   Out-File c:\FileWithEmptyLines.txt
```

UPDATE: for multiple files:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\copyforbuild*xcopy.txt" 

foreach ($f in $file)
{ 
    (Get-Content $f.FullName) | `
      Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | `
       Out-File $f.FullName
}
```

Comment: buddy , i think you have missed a } . Please update it , I need to tick the answer after that

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, fixed. I had two where-object calls and a missing brace :)

Comment: buddy , when your solution is being executed with multiple files it fails .For ex: $File = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\copyforbuild\*xcopy.txt" 

Foreach ($f in $File)
{

$var= Get-Content ($f) |`
      Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} |`
      Out-File $f
}. when i use split it two lines it works fine.

Comment: How about this: $File = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\copyforbuild*xcopy.txt"; Foreach ($f in $File){ (Get-Content $f.FullName) | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | Out-File $f.fullname }

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you save it back to the same file? Split it into 2 lines:

```
$var = gc c:\PST\1.txt | Where {$_ -ne ""}
$var > c:\pst\1.txt
```

Comment: If i tried it , it delete all the contents . Redirect operator will delete the file. If i use append >> redirect , it will end up in infinite loop and file size grows humungous

Comment: fyi, If you have a line that contains only a tab character (e.g "`t"), $_ -ne "" will not skip it